# ConnectionInfo en CrystalReport usando sqlexpress c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Vengo con un problema en mi maquina del trabajo tengo instalada la versión full del sql y en mi casa la versión express, al momento de visualizar los reportes de crystal me arroja un error adjunto el código el cual estoy usando para cargar mi reporte y luego mediante imagen lo que me arroja al momento de llamarlo.

```
private void ReportePrestamoEm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
        {
            ServerName = "PREDATORRCER\\SQLEXPRESS",
            DatabaseName = "SISROL",
            UserID = "TECNOLOGIA",
            Password = "TECNOLOGIA",
            IntegratedSecurity = false
        };
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        ParameterField pco = new ParameterField();
        ParameterFields pfields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pdvc = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pco.Name = "@ID";
        pdvc.Value = SecRep;
        //pfi.CurrentValues.Clear();
        pco.CurrentValues.Add(pdvc);
        pfields.Add(pco);


        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields;
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
        rd.Load("Z:/SisRol-Net/Reportes/ReportePrestamoEmpresa.rpt");
        //MessageBox.Show(Application.StartupPath);
        //rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "ReportePrestamoEmpresa.rpt");            
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
    }

    private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
        foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
        {
            tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía para poder resolver este pequeño detalle y poder conectarme desde mi casa o en cualquier otra instancia en la que desarrolle y no tengo la versión full